# Change name of folder if files exist inside

Tags: python

I have a very large directory tree through which I'd like to automate the act of changing folder names if the folder has files within it. Here is what I have at this time:

```
import os 
import shutil 
from os import path
import glob

# Directory to be scanned 
os.chdir('U:\\')
path = '.'

# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.txt' in file:
            dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('stuff.txt'));

            os.rename(dir_path, dir_path + '_data')
```

I'm receiving the following error but do not have admin privileges at this time to ensure the script will even work.

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'U:\' -> 'U:\_data'

Comment: Sounds like another process is accessing the directory you are trying to rename. Make sure nothing is running that might be doing this.

Comment: I think the problem is you're changing the contents of what's being iterated over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the drive name (`U:/`) this way, hence you get your first `PermissionError`. You can't also modify the directory names during the iteration (`os.walk`) or you will miss sub-folders. Therefore I propose the following:

1. Create an empty list to remember directory paths to rename
2. Once scanned, reverse the list and iterate over it - this way the longest paths should be treated first
3. Rename the directory or inform about errors

Here's the code:

```py
import os

# Directory to be scanned
os.chdir('U:\\')
path = '.'

dirs_to_rename = list()

for root_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if '.txt' in file:
            dirs_to_rename.append(root_dir)
            break

for dir_to_rename in dirs_to_rename[::-1]:
    try:
        print(f"Renaming {dir_to_rename}")
        os.rename(dir_to_rename, dir_to_rename + '_data')
    except OSError as e:
        print(f"Skipping {dir_to_rename} - {e}")
```

I quickly ran it with a few layers of folders and it seems to work just fine, but you might have to tweak it a little.

Comment: Thanks! I also just realised you should insert a `break` after `dirs_to_rename.append(root_dir)` to avoid adding the same path twice. Editted the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you have received does not sound appear to be related to any permission issues. I would recommend opening Computer Management and go to "Shared Folders > Open Files". This will show who has the files open stopping your renaming from working.

Answer (score 0):

Try `list(os.walk)`, that gets the names all at once